# Refreshing Map data when the view did appear

Tags: swift, mkmapview

Hi in the app I am making I have a tab bar so the map view doesn't reload whenever you change views using the tab bar.  I am trying to have my map view reload every time it appears.  How do I do this?  Im assuming it has to do with the `viewDidAppear` function.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   // refresh map
}
```

The **viewWillAppear** it's called every time the view is about to be displayed.